# for loops, console.log, return, undefined and scope

Tags: javascript, read-eval-print-loop, replit

Apologies for this beginners question, but I am posting this here as a last resort in trying to gain understanding of how this actually works. The problem I have is that I have to complete some exercises using repl.it where printing to the console using console.log returns undefined. For example, if I run this code inside it:

```js
function countdown(num) {
  for (let i = num; i > 0; i--) {
    console.log(i)
  }
};
countdown(10);
```

it prints:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
=> undefined
```

Now, when I run this code in VS Code, it produces the same thing but without the undefined at the bottom. Because I have to use repl.it and don't want to print undefined, I should use return right? return is better to use in this case anyway. So I change my code, but of course using return inside the for loop code block stops the loop from running, which is no good. So then I do this:

```js
function countdown(num){
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = num; i > 0; i--){
        count = i;
    }
    return count;
};
console.log(countdown(10));
```

But then I just get 1 returned. So my question is, how can I return an iterated countdown without using console.log() and any methods and by using the return keyword? This is purely for my understanding and not for any particular piece of functionality. Many thanks and sorry in advance for my confusion.

Comment: The function doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `undefined` by default. `repl.it` prints the return value of the function, VS Code doesn't.

Comment: I don't see why it would print undefined - it doesn't in the snippet (unless you are console logging the actual function)

Comment: @Pete Stack Snippets don't automatically print the value of statements, interactive REPL's do.

Comment: If you want to return all the numbers, put them in an array and return that.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, understood! Using adding return will still return undefined unless I assign it something to return though - which makes sense.. I guess the best solution for this is just to push to array, but was looking to do it without any methods.

Answer (score 2):

> how can I return an iterated countdown without using console.log() and any methods and by using the return keyword

You can get an iterated return using a generator, but you have to `yield` the value at each iteration instead of using a `return` at the end:

```js
function* countdown(num) {
  for (let i = num; i > 0; i--) {
    yield i;
  }
};
console.log(...countdown(10));
```

Or you can create an array and return it:

```js
function countdown(num) {
  const arr = [];
  for (let i = num; i > 0; i--) {
    arr.push(i);
  }
  return arr;
};
console.log(countdown(10));
```

Comment: I was about to post this solution. :P

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - I'll try that out.

Answer (score 0):

Return an array.

```js
function countdown(num) {
  let count = [];
  for (let i = num; i > 0; i--) {
    count.push(i);
  }
  return count;
};
console.log(countdown(10));
```

I used `console.log()` above because Stack Snippets don't automatically print the value of function calls. When you try this in `repl.it`, just write:

```
countdown(10)
```

and it will print the returned array automatically.

Comment: Just to add - to remove the undefined in REPL's, remove console.log().